# Aligning rotation to target along z axis

Tags: snapping

[image]

why brown object not snapping to face like other gray object in scene while i turn on all required setting.i locked rotation setting to avoid  unnecessary rotation. object should rotate along z-axis only using snapping option is it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this snapping options, and in particular with *"align rotation to target"* checked:

[image]

Moving an empty, you can notice that the Z axis is align to the target face normal and Y axis is up for the lateral faces:

[image]

But strangely this is not the case for a mesh:

[image]

Though, if you place a first mesh, then duplicate it, you can have the wanted result:

[image]

Duplication is not actually needed, you can place the object on a first face then move it again.

In my opinion (this is only an opinion), the code behind may do so that the rotation is minimal when snapping.

PS: locking rotation is not needed here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, this is great! :). It's probably worth mentioning that it snaps the origin point, not any face (but maybe that's obvious to others).

Comment: @JachymMichal, unfortunatly the former answer was incorrect...

Comment: Thank you for explanation.this is very helpful.it's solves my problem