# Align and snap one object to a slanted and rotated other object

Tags: modeling, snapping

How to align these two objects correctly? I've tried snapping option but origins normal is off. Is there a way to change it?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you are snapping needs to have its Z axis pointing in the direction of which you want it to point when snapping to the surface of another object.[image: 3d snapping in blender][image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the same snapping setting as in your question, Blender will snap applying the smallest rotation possible.

So you can do that in two steps:

- Place it in a first side
- The grab it to another side

[image]

Similar to this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167713/aligning-rotation-to-target-along-z-axis).

If you want the handle to be in another direction, rotate it first (for instance 90 degrees around Z) and snap again.

Comment: I am trying to rotate but the part is still snapped sideways. Ok it seems that I had to change the position of the origin to the edge of the part and then snap it.

Comment: @neptunereach It depends on your initial object orientation.

Comment: @neptunereach, if still does not work for you, please share your blend file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/