# How to change the sticking side in Snapping?

Tags: snapping

**I have such an object**

[image]

[image]

**How can I change the side of gluing ???**

Comment: Hello :). This can happen when an object has unapplied rotation. Did you check that?

Comment: This post may help answer your question.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167761/41087

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to say hello. I’m boiling for the second day with this problem =). Hello!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to move your *origin point*.

1. Check *Origins* ✓ tranform
2. Enable *Vertex snapping* and snap your origin point to the lowest vertex
3. Switch fo *Face snapping* and snap your object

[image]

[image]