# How do I "Glue" an object to the surface of a mesh that is using a modifier?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, constraints, parent, screw-modifier

I am trying to stick a tree to a path as the path begins to spiral/screw along the Y axis.

I have used the screw modifier to make the path spiral and then parented the tree using 3 vertices. This doesn't work, the tree becomes deformed and doesn't follow the scale, location or rotation of the path it is parented to.

I have tried using both a plane and a line curve for the path, neither work, they both have the same undesired effect. I have also tried using all of the constraints both individually and stacking the ones I think could work. I have tried parenting by 3 verts plus adding LOC,ROT and Scale constraints. No luck their either.

Is there a way to do this where the tree doesn't deform and actually stays on the surface of the path?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/113989/2214

Comment: If you need position one tree ... use Snap tool > Face Center, ALign Rotation to Targen https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167718/2214